# Why is the time complexity of binary search logN but the time complexity of a BST is N?

Tags: time-complexity, binary-search-tree, binary-search

In *Algorithms*, 4<sup>th</sup> edition by Robert Sedgewick, the time complexity table for different algorithms is given as:

[image: Time complexity table]

Based on this table, the searching time complexity of a BST is N, and of binary search in and of itself is logN.

What is the difference between the two? I have seen explanations about these separately and they made sense, however, I can't seem to understand why the searching time complexity of a BST isn't logN, as we are searching by continually breaking the tree in half and ignoring the other parts.

Comment: BST is assumed not to be balanced here, thus linear worst-case complexity

Answer (score 0):

From [binary-search-trees-bst-explained-with-examples](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/binary-search-trees-bst-explained-with-examples/)

> ...on average, each comparison allows the operations to skip about half of the tree, so that each lookup, insertion or deletion takes time proportional to the logarithm of the number of items stored in the tree,  O(log n) . However, some times the worst case can happen, when the tree isn't balanced and the time complexity is  O(n) for all three of these functions.

So, you kind of expect log(N) but it's not absolutely guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

> the searching time complexity of a BST is N, and of binary search in and of itself is logN. What is the difference between the two?

The difference is that a binary search on a sorted array *always starts at the middle element* (i.e. the *median* when *n* is odd). This cannot be guaranteed in a BST. The root *might* be the middle element, but it doesn't have to be.

For instance, this is a valid BST:

```
               10
              /
             8
            /
           5
          /
         2
        /
       1
```

...but it is not a balanced one, and so the process of finding the value 1 given the root of that tree, will include visiting *all* its nodes. If however the same values were presented in a sorted list (`1,2,5,8,10`), a binary search would start at 5 and never visit 8 or 10.

#### Adding *self-balancing* trees to the table

We can extend the given table with *self-balancing* search trees, like AVL, and then we get this:

| implementation | search | insert | delete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sequential search (unordered list) |  |  |  |
| binary search (ordered array) | lg |  |  |
| BST |  |  |  |
| AVL | lgN | lgN | lgN |